# Find a table from URL in a PNG snapshot of that same URL

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to find the equivalence of the co-ordinates of a table in a URL for the co-ordinates of that same table in a PNG file that is the snapshot of the URL.

I can find the co-ordinates of the table in the URL and I can also save the full page screenshot.

What I cannot do, is find the table's '**coordinates equivalence**' between the URL and the PNG file. The cropped table NEVER is the area of the screenshot containing the table.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```
# List of URLs
urls = [
    "https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews"
]

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

# Set up Selenium web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)  # You need to have ChromeDriver installed and in your system PATH

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
output_directory = 'output'
if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
    os.makedirs(output_directory)

for url in urls:
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Extract table using pandas
    tables = pd.read_html(response.content)

    # Assuming the desired table is the first one on the page
    table = tables[0]

    # Convert table to Markdown format
    markdown_table = table.to_markdown(index=False)

    # Print the Markdown table
    print(url)
    print(markdown_table)

    # Load the URL in Selenium
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Wait for the page to load completely (adjust the sleep duration if needed)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    # Get the maximum viewport width
    max_viewport_width = driver.execute_script("return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)")

    # Get the page height
    page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

    # Set the window size to match the maximum viewport width and the entire document height
    driver.set_window_size(max_viewport_width, page_height)

    # Find the table element using Selenium
    table_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')

    if table_element is None:
        print("Table element not found on the page.")
        continue

    # Get the location and size of the table element using Selenium
    table_location = table_element.location
    table_size = table_element.size

    print("Table Location:", table_location)
    print("Table Size:", table_size)

    if not table_location or not table_size:
        print("Invalid table location or size.")
        continue
    
    # Take a screenshot of the entire page
    full_page_screenshot_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f'full_page_{url.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0]}.png')
    driver.save_screenshot(full_page_screenshot_path)
    full_page_screenshot = Image.open(full_page_screenshot_path)

    # Check if the table width exceeds the maximum viewport width
    if table_size['width'] > max_viewport_width:
        # Calculate the number of horizontal scrolls needed
        num_scrolls = (table_size['width'] // max_viewport_width) + 1

        # Scroll horizontally and capture each section
        for i in range(num_scrolls):
            # Calculate the horizontal scroll distance
            scroll_distance = max_viewport_width * i

            # Scroll the page horizontally
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo({scroll_distance}, 0)")

            # Take a screenshot of the current section
            section_screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
            section_image = Image.open(BytesIO(section_screenshot))

            # Crop the image to the table region
            section_table_screenshot = section_image.crop(
                (table_location['x'] - scroll_distance, table_location['y'],
                 table_location['x'] + table_size['width'] - scroll_distance,
                 table_location['y'] + table_size['height'])
            )

            # Save the table section screenshot
            table_screenshot_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f'table_only_{url.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0]}_{i}.png')
            section_table_screenshot.save(table_screenshot_path)

    else:
        # Crop the image to the table region
        table_screenshot = full_page_screenshot.crop(
            (table_location['x'], table_location['y'], table_location['x'] + table_size['width'],
             table_location['y'] + table_size['height'])
        )
        table_screenshot_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f'table_only_{url.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0]}.png')
        table_screenshot.save(table_screenshot_path)

    # Generate the Markdown syntax with the table-only screenshot path
    markdown_syntax = f"![table-printout]({table_screenshot_path})"

    # Display the Markdown syntax as formatted output
    print(markdown_syntax)

# Quit the web driver
driver.quit()
```